# Parsing html content from json object

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am getting a json object as given below

```
{"id":3755,
 "type":"post",
  "slug":"burial-photos-of-hadiza-lamido",
   "url":"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/burial-photos-of-hadiza-
   lamido\/","status":"publish","title":"Burial Photos Of Late Hadiza 
        Lamido",
  "title_plain":"Burial Photos Of Late Hadiza Lamido",
  "content":"<p dir=\"ltr\"><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-
  3756\" src=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/08\/hb-
300x200.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" 
srcset=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/08\/hb-
300x200.jpg 300w, http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/wp-
content\/uploads\/2017\/08\/hb.jpg 400w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
300px\" \/><\/p>\n<p dir=\"ltr\">The former Governor of Jigawa State&#8217;s 
daughter, Hajiya Hadiza Sule Lamido was buried today, in Bamaina, Birnin  <a 
href=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/burial-photos-of-hadiza-lamido\/#more-
3755\" class=\"more-link\" rel=\"nofollow\">Read more<\/a>
<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>The former Governor of Jigawa State&#8217;s daughter, 
Hajiya Hadiza Sule Lamido was buried today, in Bamaina, Birnin <a 
class=\"read-more-link\" href=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/burial-photos-of-
 hadiza-lamido\/\">Read More<\/a><\/p>\n",
}
```

And I unable to parse value corresponding to content in Android.
Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it simply like this

```
Html.fromHtml(response["content"])
```

Or you can user jsoup library to parse it with more securely.

https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup-2.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use online tool like http://jsonparseronline.com/ to check if JSON is well formatted.
2. In this case there are line breaks within value for keys like "url", "title","content" and it is failing parsing. Also extra comma at the end makes the parsing go wrong.

So after removing those line breaks and additional comma then content is good for parsing.

```
{"id":3755,"type":"post", "slug":"burial-photos-of-hadiza-lamido","url":"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/burial-photos-of-hadiza-lamido\/","status":"publish","title":"Burial Photos Of Late Hadiza Lamido",  "title_plain":"Burial Photos Of Late Hadiza Lamido","content":"<p dir=\"ltr\"><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-3756\" src=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/08\/hb-300x200.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" srcset=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/08\/hb-300x200.jpg 300w, http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/08\/hb.jpg 400w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" \/><\/p>\n<p dir=\"ltr\">The former Governor of Jigawa State&#8217;sdaughter, Hajiya Hadiza Sule Lamido was buried today, in Bamaina, Birnin  <a href=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/burial-photos-of-hadiza-lamido\/#more-3755\" class=\"more-link\" rel=\"nofollow\">Read more<\/a><\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>The former Governor of Jigawa State&#8217;s daughter, Hajiya Hadiza Sule Lamido was buried today, in Bamaina, Birnin <a class=\"read-more-link\" href=\"http:\/\/www.adaikeji.com\/burial-photos-of- hadiza-lamido\/\">Read More<\/a><\/p>\n"}
```

Hope this helps to correct your problem.